# convert html table data into JSON array object in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have an HTML table data now I want to convert that data into JSON array object.

Created one table in reactjs I want to export that data into excel for that I need to convert that html data into Json object

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is kind of confusing and that is why it got down-voted.
So if you have a table in HTML it is not really and issue to convert it to Json.. Just do it..

But if you want to export an HTML to Excel you don't need to use a Json as a middleman.

Try to look at this solution http://sheetjs.com/demos/table.html

Good Luck!